# Unable to understand ruby error

Tags: ruby

OK, so I am reading "Agile Web Development with Rails" and working on the depot application.  For those who have the book it is Chapter 9.3 Iteration D3: Adding a button.

Prior to this section we created a session to hold our "shopping cart"

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery

  private
    def current_cart
      Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      cart = Cart.create
      session[:cart_id] = cart.id
      cart
    end
end
```

Making it so any controller we create that extends ApplicationController has access to our cart.

In this section we edit the "create" function of the  LineItemsController class which extends ApplicationControler.

The original create method looks like this

```
def create
  @line_item = LineItem.new(params[:line_item])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @line_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @line_item, status: :created, location: @line_item }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The book says to modify if like this.

```
def create
  @cart = current_cart

  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])

  @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: product)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @line_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @line_item, status: :created, location: @line_item }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I've triple checked the code.  I have duplicated it from the book.  Not being a ruby expert I don't know what I am missing.  The error it gives me is this.

```
ArgumentError in LineItemsController#create

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
Rails.root: /Users/jandrews/Projects/pragprog_ruby/depot

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
activerecord (3.1.3) lib/active_record/relation.rb:318:in `destroy'
activerecord (3.1.3) lib/active_record/base.rb:442:in `destroy'
app/models/cart.rb:2:in `<class:Cart>'
app/models/cart.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `block in load_file'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:455:in `load_file'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:489:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `block in const_missing'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `each'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `const_missing'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:501:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `block in const_missing'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `each'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `const_missing'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:7:in `current_cart'
app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:43:in `create'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run__1422100127945824718__process_action__3684163507935076470__callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:201:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.1.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:247:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:331:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:477:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.1.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:456:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/jandrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/jandrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/jandrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
Request

Parameters:

{"authenticity_token"=>"tx+PRUMMQpyZ48Yw9ZLoWZ60HOo1992tpQXbKFkF4YM=",
 "product_id"=>"5"}
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None
```

The code that actually does the submit looks like this in the browser

```
<form action="/line_items?product_id=5" class="button_to" method="post">
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" 
      value="tx+PRUMMQpyZ48Yw9ZLoWZ60HOo1992tpQXbKFkF4YM=">
  </div>
</form>
```

Sorry forgot to mention if I add the lines one by one from the original it fails on the line with.  That's as far as I was able to debug since my knowledge of ruby is still limited atm.

```
@cart = current_cart
```

Cart model file.

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, dependent: destroy
end
```

Comment: What are the first 2 lines of your `app/models/cart.rb` file?

Comment: sorry about the last comment grabbed the wrong code.  I'll edit the question and put it there.

Comment: cart.rb under app/models/cart.rb should contain class definition for Cart model. first line should look like `class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base`

Comment: sorry, been looking at this too long. I grabbed the file in the wrong directory.  I have updated the correct file.

Comment: 'wrong number of arguments' is an incomplete error message. Can you provide the whole thing?

Comment: updated with the complete error page and trace.

Comment: @thenetimp Thanks for asking that questions, I just ran into the same problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of

```
has_many :line_items, dependent: destroy
```

put

```
has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy # the colon!!
```

Comment: Thank you!  Getting use to the new Syntax is interesting.